# Как устранить Утечку Памяти

Tags: java, android

Здорова всем. За ранее я извиняюсь, Я не силён на русском языке. Я еще новичок на разработке андроид приложение. Я почти закончил свой первый проект. Ну вот я наткнулся на такое проблему как утечки памяти. Я раньше не столковался и не устранял эту проблему. Ну вот я уже две недели не могу решить эту проблему. Я попробовал разные варианты но ничьё не помогает. Я прочитал, что бы найти утечки памяти нужно использовать LeakCanary, потом я установил LeakCanary и получил сообщение об утечки памяти.

Вот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну вот я не могу понят что, где, как, и где все это находится. Коллеги прошу ваши помощи.
Если можете помочь то могу скинуть приложению с установленным LeakCanary, чтобы увидеть все эту безобразию)).

---

Код, связанный с анимацией:

```
private void animload(){
    int centerX = (mview.getRight());
    int centerY = (mview.getBottom());

    int startRadius = 0;
    // get the final radius for the clipping circle
    int endRadius = Math.max(mview.getWidth()+200, mview.getHeight()+200);

    // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
    Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(mview, centerX, centerY, startRadius, endRadius);

    anim.setDuration(600);
    // make the view visible and start the animation
    anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
    mview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    anim.start();
}
```

Comment: Скиньте код аниматора, он у вас используется, но `mListeners` не закрывается в `onPause` как подобает. Изучите: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/debug/memoryleak.php

Comment: @IFr0z у меня есть еще несколько вопросов. Вы можете дать мне свой email?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87622/ifr0z

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4112599 + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631818/leakcanary-report-leak-in-inputmethodmanager